Xcode crashing on second build with EXC_ARITHMETIC (SIGFPE) / TPCSignatureStore
Happens on second build, meaning
Launch Xcode → Build → OK
Change a line → Build → Xcode crashes
Beginning of stack trace below
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               Xcode [64511]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               15.4 (22622)
Build Info:            IDEApplication-22622000000000000~2 (15F31d)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2024-07-31 16:18:09.2869 +1000
OS Version:            macOS 14.1.1 (23B81)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        390641C9-2924-838D-3E81-861399026A69


Time Awake Since Boot: 11000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: disabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_ARITHMETIC (SIGFPE)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 8 Floating point exception: 8
Terminating Process:   exc handler [64511]

Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   CallstackAnalysis                   0x7ffb0f9677f5 -[TPCSignatureStore isSignatureStoreUsable:] + 46
1   IDEPerformanceDebugger                 0x303a0e4af RuntimePerformanceIssueDebuggerAddition.populateSignatureStore() + 815
2   IDEPerformanceDebugger                 0x303a0dda8 closure #3 in closure #1 in RuntimePerformanceIssueDebuggerAddition.fetchLogs(bundleIdentifier:platform:) + 72
3   IDEPerformanceDebugger                 0x303a1062c partial apply for closure #3 in closure #1 in RuntimePerformanceIssueDebuggerAddition.fetchLogs(bundleIdentifier:platform:) + 12
4   libswiftDispatch.dylib              0x7ff81b7d4331 partial apply for thunk for @callee_guaranteed () -> (@out A, @error @owned Error) + 17
5   libswiftDispatch.dylib              0x7ff81b7d49c9 thunk for @callee_guaranteed () -> (@out A, @error @owned Error)partial apply + 9
6   libswiftDispatch.dylib              0x7ff81b7d1cf8 closure #1 in closure #1 in OS_dispatch_queue._syncHelper<A>(fn:execute:rescue:) + 88
7   libswiftDispatch.dylib              0x7ff81b7d4291 partial apply for thunk for @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 17
8   libswiftDispatch.dylib              0x7ff81b7cda1e thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 14
9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80552159a _dispatch_client_callout + 8
10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80552e513 _dispatch_async_and_wait_invoke + 98
11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80552159a _dispatch_client_callout + 8
12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80552d8e1 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 993
13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80552d4f2 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 31
14  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff8057e4056 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
15  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff8057a32b5 __CFRunLoopRun + 2459
16  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff8057a2352 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 557
17  HIToolbox                           0x7ff8100449d9 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
18  HIToolbox                           0x7ff8100447e6 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 665
19  HIToolbox                           0x7ff810044531 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 66
20  AppKit                              0x7ff808db2885 _DPSNextEvent + 880
21  AppKit                              0x7ff8096a6348 -[NSApplication(NSEventRouting) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1304
22  DVTKit                                 0x17e217914 -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 366
23  AppKit                              0x7ff808da3dfa -[NSApplication run] + 603
24  DVTKit                                 0x17e216a0f -[DVTApplication run] + 54
25  AppKit                              0x7ff808d77e10 NSApplicationMain + 816
26  dyld                                0x7ff8053403a6 start + 1942


After spending hours trying to fix this so I can write code again, I found that

The issue does not happen when Xcode preferences are reset (~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist removed)
The lines in the plist that affect whether it crashes or not are within this block

"DVTAnalytics.AnalyticsDirectHangPointSource.lastRefreshAttemptDate" =     {
    DVTUserDefaultsCachingCache =         {
        "<bundle id> 5.0.5 2838 com.apple.platform.iphoneos" = "2024-07-31 13:12:12 +0000";
        "<bundle id> 5.0.6 2843 com.apple.platform.iphoneos" = "2024-07-31 07:15:22 +0000";
        "<bundle id> 5.1.0 2844 com.apple.platform.iphoneos" = "2024-07-31 04:42:07 +0000";
    };
    DVTUserDefaultsCachingKeysRecentlyUsed =         (
        "<bundle id> 5.1.0 2844 com.apple.platform.iphoneos",
        "<bundle id> 5.0.6 2843 com.apple.platform.iphoneos",
        "<bundle id> 5.0.5 2838 com.apple.platform.iphoneos"
    );
};

Where 5.1.0 etc is the app version and 2844 etc is the build
Spent way too much time on this to dig further, but sharing the above in case it helps someone.
To avoid flushing preferences each time, a workaround is to remove the section with
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode "DVTAnalytics.AnalyticsDirectHangPointSource.lastRefreshAttemptDate"
Might need to read the defaults for them to be read within Xcode as there is some caching that's very inconsistent in behaviour
defaults read com.apple.dt.Xcode
EDIT Also just found that removing ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Products folder seems to fix the issue. The products get fetched back pretty quickly but issue doesn't come back, at least not instantly.
Do share any findings you get on this if you encounter the same issue as I found nothing Googling
